# Creating Additional Fields as Necessary

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, list-form

I train people who process claims.  We have nothing in place for tracking the trainees' progress on the claims they've worked so that instructors can review them.  Hence, I've decided Sharepoint is the answer.

I've created a list that allows students to enter information on the form and set the status of the claim.  The review can then review it and reset the status.  However, I've encountered one major issue.

The trainees have to enter the claimant's dependents and information about those dependents.  My IT staff is giving me very little room to work here.  But I need to have some way of adding additional fields for dependent information if the claimant has multiple dependents.

I'm using Infopath 2010 and Sharepoint 2013.  Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: I think I have it figured out.  I've used Infopath to create a new form; however, now I have no idea how to make this new form my default "New Item" form.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with SharePoint 2010 what I think you want to. SharePoint 2013 is similar.

You can open InfoPath for the list like this.

[image]

When you open InfoPath form, you can add new columns to list like this

[image]

After adding new column or design form, you should publish form. When you use quick publish, InfoPath form will be the default new item form for the list.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This tells me how to customize the default Sharepoint List form; however, the default Sharepoint List form will not accept repeating tables (which I absolutely need).  So I've created a custom form in Infopath, but I need to make this form that I created the default "New Item" form.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I did not get you need repeating table, from your question :/

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely add additional information. You will create additional list columns required and write rules in infopath, if additional dependent is checked, additional fields will be visible otherwise not.

But this explanation is on a very high level, can you provide the screen shot of the list columns, and your existing infopath form?

Comment: I cannot share a screenshot, but the list columns relevant are
Dependent  |  Relationship  |  Date of Birth  |  Age

Essentially, I have that in one table title Dependent Status.  Since I have no way of identifying how many dependents each claimant might have, I need the trainee to be bale to add another set of dependent fields for every additional dependent, whether it's one dependent or nine dependents.

Comment: That is possible but that requires extensive programming.

In SharePoint, lookup columns form the basis for relationships between lists. In the SharePoint List Data Models reference implementation, the Site Columns and Content Types feature manifest defines several lookup columns as site columns. For example, the following code defines a lookup field on the Machines list.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798409.aspx